# C macro using two macros

Tags: c, macros

I want to make a macro to utilize two macros

```
#define BUZZER_ON func_buzz(1);\
                  flag_buzzer_on = 1;\


#define BUZZER_OFF func_buzz(0);\
                  flag_buzzer_on = 0;\

#define BUZZER_TOGGLE ((flag_buzzer_on == 1) ? BUZZER_OFF : BUZZER_ON ) ;
```

where func_buzz is function to turn buzzer on or off depending on value passed

BUZZER ON and BUZZER OFF MACRO is working correctly

but when i use MACRO BUZZER_TOGGLE i get error

expression expected : or ) before ;

How to write MACRO BUZZER_TOGGLE

Comment: This is one example of why you should use functions, not macros, whenever possible. Macros are much more error-prone.

Comment: The ternary conditional expression is an *expression*, and all parts of it must also be *expressions*. You can't have statements in it. If you need statements, use plain `if else`.

Comment: Also please don't rewrite your code into the question, please *copy-paste* it. That way you won't be adding other errors or problems unrelated to the one you're asking about (there are multiple errors in the shown code, unrelated to the problem you're asking about). Also please make sure you post a [mcve], preferably one that replicates the error you ask about. And also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output, plus add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: `#define BUZZER_TOGGLE flag_buzzer_on = !flag_buzzer_on; func_buzz(flag_buzzer_on);`

Comment: Please don't invent your own secret macro language. `func_buzz(1); flag_buzzer_on = 1;` is perfectly readable C. While `BUZZER_ON;` is some secret society handshake that only the initiated few understands. That's the root of your problem - the specific compiler error comes from `?:` not being the same thing as `if - else`.

Answer (score 2):

remember that in your case you can think of macro expansion simplified as text replacement although that's not quite correct as @Eric Postpischil has correcty stated in his comment.

In your case the line

```
 BUZZER_TOGGLE;
```

is expanded to

```
((flag_buzzer_on == 1) ? func_buzz(0); flag_buzzer_on = 0; : func_buzz(1); flag_buzzer_on = 1;) ;;
```

(assuming the second `#define BUZZER_ON` in the question is a typo for `BUZZER_OFF`).

You can see that this is no valid statement.
You could make it valid if you defined

```
#define BUZZER_ON  (func_buzz(1), flag_buzzer_on = 1)
```

and `BUZZER_OFF` accordingly

but maybe it's easier just to use simple functions instead of macros.

Comment: Macro replacement substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text. E.g., it cannot form new tokens, aside from the `##` operator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil your right of course, I've changed the wording to make clear it's a simplification